# c# WebAPI pass document path as parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

In testing my code below, having it like this:

```
http://localhost:49494/api/DownloadFile/q%3a%5cLetters%5cOnlineReminder.pdf
```

Causes this exception:
**A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client**

Having it like this:

```
http://localhost:49494/api/DownloadFile?q%3a%5cLetters%5cOnlineReminder.pdf
```

**The path to the document (FullPath) in the function is null**.

Here's the code:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/DownloadFile/{*FullPath}")]
public IHttpActionResult DownloadFile(string FullPath)
{
    if (FullPath == null)
        return NotFound();

    System.IO.MemoryStream Stream = _ArchiveRepository.GetDownloadStream(FullPath);

    return new MemoryStreamResult(Stream, "application/octet-stream");
}
```

I have coded a MemoryStreamresult as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scott Hanselman has written about this in http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx. You might want to check the requestPathInvalidCharacters property of the  node in your web.config. the symbol % by default is an invalid character

maybe you should try requesting with this form yourlocal/api/DownloadFile/?FullPath=q%3a%5cLetters%5cOnlineReminder.pdf, or else remove the character from requestPathInvalidCharacters

Comment: Actually had to use the querystring with the FullPath as a parameter. .../DownloadFile?FullPath=q%3a%5cLetters%5cOnlineReminder.pdf